# Symfony 2 : Route requirements correct usage

Tags: php, symfony

Using Symfony 2, I wonder if the following usage of [route requirements](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html) is correct or should it be dedicated to specific regular expressions ?

```yaml
#routing.yml

fbn_guide_articles:
    path:  /{articles}
    defaults: { _controller: FBNGuideBundle:Guide:articles }
    requirements : 
        articles : infos|restaurants|winemakers|events|tutorials|shops
```

An alternative could be the following at controller level:

```yaml
#routing.yml

fbn_guide_articles:
    path:  /{articles}
    defaults: { _controller: FBNGuideBundle:Guide:articles }
```

```php
class GuideController extends Controller
{
    private static $articlesEntities = array(
        'infos' => 'Info',
        'restaurants' => 'Restaurant',
        'winemakers' => 'Winemaker',
        'events' => 'Event',
        'tutorials' => 'Tutorial',
        'shops' => 'Shop',
    );

    public function articlesAction($articles)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($articles, self::$articlesEntities)) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }

        // Do the stuff
    }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you had used annotations, there was a way better option for you. It may still work but you might need to play with it in your yml file. [Using a custom class constant for @Route annotation requirements](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/pey5/using-a-custom-class-constant-for-route-annotation-requirements). After implementing same thing in this blog, try `articles : _try to put validator namespace here_` and see if it works for yml file.

Comment: @BentCoder Thanks. I understand your code but my question is : is my usage of requirements correct or is it a bit far from the idea behind requirements ? If I use my second solution I wil have to place any route like `/{something}` before `fbn_guide_articles routes` if I  want to avoid a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Requirements of a route is a more "declarative" way to do the same things, but that works early than controller action.

So, it's a fine solution if logic of your routing not too complex. In this case, implementation of same process in the controller is just a duplication of the framework functions that already tested and work fine.

Comment: Exactly. So I can keep my requirements (my logic is really simple here) and avoid to check it at controller level ?

Comment: It depends. 
You probably should not to repeat this check and following throwing 404-exception at the controller level, because it's just duplication. 
But at the next levels (such as your domain code, services, etc) you may need to do verification of this values. You may to use only simple [assertions](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.assert.php)  or always explicitly check the value in the code, but the wrong value at these levels should not cause an 404 error (because it is not router/controller level), but should throw some inner exception. So it depends on your application.

Comment: I understand. I keep my solution. These requirements values are just needed to redirect on the correct controller action (main navigation menu), nothing else. I will use assertions at tests level.